# Why does an Alcubierre drive, travelling FTL, violate causality, if the universe expanding FTL doesn't?

Tags: space-expansion, causality, faster-than-light, warp-drives

An Alcubierre drive seems to be plausible as a means to travel faster than light, because

- it doesn't move the object itself, but the space around it.
- it's said that matter and information can't move through space faster than light, but space itself can.

However, it turns out that an Alcubierre drive still can't achieve superluminal speed without violating causality, because:

- the limit of speed of light doesn't apply only to matter and information, but to anything that moves from one point to another in space.
- anything that moves faster than light also makes information that comes out of it travel back in time, which violates causality.
- since the warp bubble itself moves faster than light within the rest of the universe, an Alcubierre drive will violate causality as it moves faster than light.

But if this is true, why can the universe expand faster than light, without time travel and therefore violation of causality happening? What makes it different to a warp bubble?

Comment: *but space itself can* "Space itself" isn't moving through space (or some kind of meta-space). Space isn't going anywhere, it's just expanding. The expansion rate isn't a speed, it's a speed divided by distance, so it has units of 1/time.

Comment: I've had a lot of arguments, on physics forums, about the difference between expansion & relative motion, but it's great to see it so clearly related to time.  (I don't understand why people think nothingness, rather than objects bounding it, could be moved relative to anything else.)  The gist of that difference was explicitly described by Einstein in the 1916 edition (the first "pop sci" version) of 1915's General Relativity, somewhere near the middle of the book, which was printed in several different languages!  Even so, some half-arsed impression managed, magically, to leak out...!

Comment: I guess it was a collective spelling error:  "No thing" should never have been contracted into "nothing".

Answer (score 14):

In any curved spacetime we can still talk about *local* reference frames that are small enough scale we can ignore the curvature. We also can ask if there are [closed timelike curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_timelike_curve) (CTC) which basically is asking whether we can time-travel to our past selves. *CTCs are strongly thought to be impossible in reality*.

The universe is thought to be *spatially* [flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_of_the_universe), but the space*time* as a whole is curved. CTC's are impossible: at each point in spacetime you have an "age of the universe". To be precise, this is *maximum* path-length (proper time) a geodesic could have between the big-bang singularity and said point. Any time-like or light-like curve is moving in the direction of increasing age of the universe; this is just as strong a concept of "future" and "past" as in flat spacetime.

With a *single* warp-drive you don't have CTC's. But you can still get CTC's with multiple warp-drives. Suppose you build a warp-drive on Earth and send it out into space. You start with an (almost) flat *initial-condition* and then generate a strongly curved spacetime (your warp bubble). *Starting from a flat spacetime* (or for very large scales from the spacetime [of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric)), *is much more physically realistic* than starting from any other spacetime. You have to *make* your weird and wonderful curvature from an "empty canvas" !

With a warp-bubble, the highly curved spacetime is on a small scale. This allows us to glue two bubble spacetimes together so long as the ships don't get very close to each-other. If we consider two Earths, moving relative to each-other, that each make a warp-drive, we can set up the system to [generate CTCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyonic_antitelephone). This is one reason we suspect this to be impossible.

There is another reason to suspect making warp drives is impossible: Geodesics would have to diverge in some region, which is an anti-gravity effect. Neither matter nor light can make anti-gravity (antimatter has positive mass just like matter). The "attractive gravity only" rule is more precisely defined as an [energy condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_condition) and [at least one of these is violated by warp drives](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.105.064038). Violating certain energy conditions would make the speed of sound faster than light which also allows for time-travel paradoxes.

In general, no known solution with CTC's is physically realistic. They either involve infinitely large systems that cannot be setup from an "empty canvas" or violations of energy conditions. For example, the [Kerr metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric) concentrates it's energy condition violation in it's singularity. Real black holes are thought to lack this feature and [be much deadlier instead](https://jila.colorado.edu/%7Eajsh/insidebh/realistic.html).

Comment: Unfortunately the strict "no negative energies" has been punched out. The space inside a non-vacuum dielectric capacitor has a negative energy component proportional to the energy stored on the capacitor plates, and this energy is the same energy required to pull the dielectric out of the capacitor while it is charged. So far, all known dielectrics have a breakdown voltage too low to make an absolute negative energy region but there's no proof this must be the case.

Comment: Incidentally I beg to differ about cannot get CTCs with a single warp bubble. Use a supermassive black hole. I am reasonably convinced that such a drive would enable climbing back out of one.

Comment: @joshua: there is positive energy in the electric field also, which always exceeds the energy it takes to pull away the dielectric. But your "negative energy" exists when particles bind together. However, the mass defect is always less than the mass of the particles, so the energy conditions hold. You are right there is no proof.

Comment: I know this comes a little late but I think opening a new question would get dinged, so - if there were a single preferred reference frame in which all warp drives in principle had to operate - let's call it subspace - that would prevent CTCs right?

Comment: @PeterMoore: There is nice, unique "zero velocity" frame you can define in the early universe. Run all of these geodesics forward in time and use their *proper time* as your universal time. When there are *caustics* (multiple geodesics that pass through the same point; not to be confused with singularities), choose the *largest* proper time. Allow FTL but all paths must strictly increase in universal time. These FTL rules aren't Lorentz-invariant, of course. How physics would work inside the engine nacelles of your jump drives is left as an exercise for Worldbuilding stack exchange.

Comment: Haha thanks @KevinKostlan. My thought was that if the Alcubierre drive is actually manipulating the fabric of spacetime itself, it seems at least conceivable that this effect occurs in a preferred frame ("subspace"). And if that's so, and it's impossible ever to go backwards in time in that frame, then the drive wouldn't lead to CTCs. The upshot, I believe, is that there would still be large time dilation for observers moving relative to subspace due to the relativity of simultaneity. What seems like instant travel at warp could seem like 1000s of years on Earth, but no paradoxes at least.

Comment: @PeterMoore: "if the Alcubierre drive is actually manipulating the fabric of spacetime itself". Matter/energy already does this, and does so without a preferred frame. But what if somehow we discover a *different* way to bend spacetime that is not limited by allowed stress-energy tensors? Then it could well make use a "subspace" etc. "What seems like instant travel at warp could seem like 1000s of years on Earth". This is already the case with special relativity, no curved spacetime needed. FTL would mean traveling to Alpha Centauri and returning in time for dinner.

Comment: @KevinKostlan good point. Re: FTL and time dilation, if FTL works only in one preferred frame, you have to consider the frame of Earth relative to that preferred frame to determine the speed that Earth residents will observe. IIRC he factor is 1/B, i.e., if earth is moving at .002c relative to subspace (CMB in this case) then instantaneous travel in subspace would appear as 500c from Earth perspective; anything faster would allow CTCs. So, still much better than normal SR but not a magic bullet. 3 days to Alpha Centauri, so not quite home for dinner. :) But rules out inter-galactic, etc.

Comment: @PeterMoore: The Sun's velocity with respect to "subspace" (0.0012c relative to CMB) does not limit the round trip time. If you travel in the direction of Earth's true velocity you can go back in time (in Earths frame) up to 4.3 seconds/light hour. This sounds like time travel but it isn't: when you return to Earth you lose all that time gained. Extremely high FTL velocities shorten the round-trip Earth time as much as you want, for both a stationary and moving Earth, but you always arrive later than you left.

Comment: @KevinKostlan oh I think I see what you're saying. The "relativity of simultaneity" issue doesn't matter because even you're technically in Earth's past while walking on Alpha Centauri, when you make the return trip the effect will cancel out and you'll always arrive home after you left. Do I have it right now?

Comment: @PeterMoore: Yes that's correct. To summarize: In special relativity you use (Cartesian) reference frames. Without FTL everything moves forward in time in *all* such frames. FTL in frame A is moving back in time in some frame B. FTL+Lorentz invariance means CTCs can created by setting up FTL drives in both A and B. Warp drives depend on "exotic matter", thought to be impossible. But FTL with a universal subspace introduces new physics which break Lorentz invariance, preventing CTCs.

Comment: @KevinKostlan perfect! You've bolstered my understanding and hope for the feasibility of the warp drive, even if a longshot. :) I wish I understood GR a bit better to understand the remaining issues but you've been more than generous enough that I'll leave those questions for another day. Thanks much.

Answer (score 4):

There are two fundamental differences between these two cases.

First, an Alcubierre warp tube is supposed to be something that you *make*. The problem is that if you can make one of them, and the laws of physics are Poincaré (Lorentz+translation) invariant, then you can make two of them in a configuration that violates causality, as Kevin Kostlan said.

This is a nonissue for the large-scale structure of spacetime, because you can't make two universes, or even one universe. Its shape is (by assumption) out of your control, and it has, as a matter of fact, no closed timelike curves.

Second, the expansion of the universe is, in a certain sense, faster than $c\triangleq 299{,}792{,}458\text{ m/s}$, but it isn't faster than *light*. A galaxy distant enough to have a recession speed larger than $c$ won't outrun a receding beam of light at the same distance, because the light's recession speed is even larger. $c$ is only the speed of light in inertial coordinates, and the standard cosmological coordinates aren't inertial.

If you go through an Alcubierre tube – even a unique one made by God so there are no causality issues – then you do outpace light that travels between the endpoints outside the tube. Nothing analogous to that ever happens in cosmology.

Comment: To clarify: the reverse of an Alcubierre tube is OK: A light-ray passing through the center of earth will take ~nanoseconds *longer* to get to it's destination than a light-ray geodesic that is (very-slightly) bent around Earth's gravity well. But no localized physically-possible spacetime curvature (such as spinning black holes, etc) could end up making light take *less* time than flat spacetime.